# When I try to run automatic tests in Appium on the Kobiton device farm, I get an exception

Tags: java, appium, kobiton

When I try to run automatic tests in Appium on the Kobiton device farm, I get an exception: Could not start a new session. Only W3C sessions are supported. Please make sure your server is up to date.

I have no idea what could be causing the problem. I can't find a thread anywhere. related to this, and a month ago I was able to run automatic tests on the farm without any problems.

The content of the RunApplication class was generated automatically by Kobiton.

Regardless of the sent application or choosing a different device, there is always the same error.

Logs:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass *RunApplication
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Only W3C sessions are supported. Please make sure your server is up to date. 
Host info: host: '', ip: '127.0.0.1'
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.6', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:app=kobiton-store:v528820, appium:captureScreenshots=true, appium:deviceGroup=KOBITON, appium:deviceName=Galaxy*, appium:deviceOrientation=portrait, platformName=ANDROID, appium:platformVersion=1*, appium:sessionDescription=, appium:sessionName=Automation test session}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {app: kobiton-store:v528820, captureScreenshots: true, deviceGroup: KOBITON, deviceName: Galaxy*, deviceOrientation: portrait, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 1*, sessionDescription: , sessionName: Automation test session}}]
Capabilities {}
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:154)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:224)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:116)
    at Testy.BaseConfiguration.AppiumAndroidDoctor.RunApplication(AppiumAndroidDoctor.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:180)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

and my Desired Capabilities

```
package Testy.BaseConfiguration;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;


public class AppiumAndroidDoctor {

    public AndroidDriver driver;
    
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void RunApplication() throws IOException
    {
        
      String kobitonServerUrl = "myKobitonServerUrl";
        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        
        capabilities.setCapability("sessionName", "Automation test session");
        capabilities.setCapability("sessionDescription", "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        capabilities.setCapability("captureScreenshots", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "kobiton-store:v528820");        
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceGroup", "KOBITON");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy*");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "1*");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android"); 
        
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(kobitonServerUrl),capabilities); 
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use java-client latest version
https://github.com/appium/java-client

```
<dependency>  
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>8.3.0</version> //for today is 8.3.0
</dependency>
```